# How can the delay before displaying meteor collections be best addressed?

Tags: meteor, loading, user-experience, webpage-rendering

Before displaying the items from a collection, meteor seems to do some processing that leaves the client window without updates. You can see this live if you surf to http://madewith.meteor.com on a reasonable machine. My 2.6GHz 4GB RAM laptop takes about 5 seconds to render the items in the list, during which there is no indication of progress and a new user in a hurry could reasonably believe the page has finished loading.

Is there a way to incrementally display items from a collection, such that the server pushes to the client the first items of data on the wire, and the browser renders them, while new items are received? Akin to HTTP's [chunked transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Or is the only solution to display a spinner graphic while loading the collection, similar to what https://atmosphere.meteor.com/ does (the "doing something smart" message)?

Comment: It's not very meaningful. It can mean too many things. Maybe it's better you change it to [tag:incremental-display] or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the xhr of the madewith app, you'll see that all (87 at this moment) apps load in the same request. So I don't think 'incrementally' displaying data is going to help in this case.

The issue is just that meteor apps take a while to initialise. I'm not sure if this can be improved in the future, but for now, yes, I think displaying a spinner is the best solution.

Regarding how to know when the data is ready, you can use the `onReady` callback on a collection, or see this [PR](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/273) for a better solution coming soon.

Comment: By incremental display, I mean a method similar to HTTP's [chunked transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), whereby the client doesn't need to wait for the content to finish transferring.

Comment: Hmm.. but the HTML sent is very simple. The JS is long and complex (this, along with the time taken to init the `livedata-connection` is no doubt the cause of the slowness). But I'm not sure browsers support incremental JS loading (do they?)