# Displaying loader while meteor collection loads

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I have a template, `task_list`, that looks like this:

```
{{#each tasks}}
    {{> task}}
{{/each}}
```

`Template.task_list.tasks` returns a collection and in the ui, it seems to take a bit of time to load.

While the collection is loading, I'd like to show a loading indicator.

Any ideas on how I might be able to do that?

BTW, I did try the templates' `rendered` event on task_list template, however it gets fired before the list is actually loaded. I also tried using `rendered` on the `task` template but it seems to never get called.

Comment: I was wondering about the same issue at [How can the delay before displaying meteor collections be best addressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773672/how-can-the-delay-before-displaying-meteor-collections-be-best-addressed)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Meteor 1.0.4 update**: Now that [template-level subscriptions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) are available and the preferred pattern to using iron:router or standalone subscriptions,

> There is a complementary function `Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()` which returns true when all of the subscriptions called with `this.subscribe` are ready.
>
> Inside the template's HTML, you can use the built-in helper `Template.subscriptionsReady`, which is an easy pattern for showing loading indicators in your templates when they depend on data loaded from subscriptions.

Example:

```
Template.notifications.onCreated(function () {
  // Use this.subscribe inside onCreated callback
  this.subscribe("notifications");
});
<template name="notifications">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    <!-- This is displayed when all data is ready. -->
    {{#each notifications}}
      {{> notification}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    Loading...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

This is better than having a generic loading template for the whole page, because the loading section is localized to the part of the page that actually has new data.

---

**Pre-Meteor 1.0.4**:

The idea is to pass an onReady function to [`Meteor.subscribe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe):

```
Meteor.subscribe('tasks', function onReady() {
  Session.set('tasksLoaded', true);
});
```

Then, make your template depend on the `tasksLoaded` session variable. In the client JavaScript:

```
Template.task_list.helpers({
  tasksLoaded: function () {
    return Session.get('tasksLoaded');
  }
});
```

In your template:

```
<template name="task_list">
  {{#if tasksLoaded}}
    {{#each tasks}}
      {{> task}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <img src="http://viewvc.svn.mozilla.org/vc/addons/trunk/bandwagon/skin/images/spinner.gif?revision=18591&view=co&pathrev=18591">
  {{/if}}
```

*UPDATE*: With [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) you have a direct option to specify a `loading` template which will be displayed while the subscription is loading.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. This was spot on.

Comment: the function is fine but how do you make a callback when all the subscriptions are ready?

Comment: Related question: I want to have a mini-loader in my navbar in addition to an `iron-router` style loader on the main page that's loading.  Is there a way in my `header` template to somehow check for the **rest** of my templates on the page being ready?  All I can figure out is how to wait for *that* template that the loader is actually in - which is loaded very quickly. I tried absolute positioning CSS to just "put" my mini-loader up in the navbar from my `iron-router` loader but it gets messed up on certain pages and transitions.  Having it actually in my header would be ideal.

Comment: What would be the way to do it if I use subscriptions through iron:router? I re-use components on multiple routes, while each route loads different data. So subscribing in the router makes sense to me for my use case.

Answer (score 5):

[Dan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu) answer was definitely spot on, but I want to remind that I belive autopublish package has to be removed for it to actually work.

```
meteor remove autopublish
```

Plus, I recommend [spin package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/spin) for a nice looking spinner.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some nice packages released in the meantime. Check out these two:

1. [Spin](https://github.com/SachaG/meteor-spin) - displays a spinning wheel. With Iron Router, you can specify a loading template which shows the spinning wheel.
2. [Iron Router Progress](https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress) - shows a progress bar on the top of the page (Youtube style)

They both work pretty much out of the box, have a look at their documentation for more advanced options.

Comment: Those packages do come in handy. In the meantime, Meteor has released v1.0.4, which brings in template-level subscriptions and a `Template.subscriptionsReady` helper. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12880255/1269037) for more details.