# Callback when all Template items finished rendering in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm getting a collection of records and placing them in a Template, having them rendered `{{#each}}` and I want to display a loading icon until the last DOM node is rendered.

My problem is that I have not found a way to query a state/fire a callback on the last item rendered aka the last DOM node to be updated/re-drawn.

It looks a bit like this in my HTML file:

```
<template name="stuff">
    {{#each items}}
        <div class="coolView">{{cool_stuff}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And in the client-side JS file:

```
// returns all records of Stuff belonging to the currently logged-in user
Template.stuff.items = function () {
    Session.set('loading_stuff', true);
    return Items.find({owner: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {created_time: -1}});
};

Template.stuff.rendered = function() {
    // every time something new is rendered, there will have been loading of the DOM. 
    // wait a short while after the last render to clear any loading indication.
    Session.set('loading_stuff', true);
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {Session.set('loading_stuff', false);}, 300);
};
```

The Session variable `loading_stuff` is queried in a Handlebars helper, returning the name of the loading class (with a loader icon GIF) if it's `true`.

The reason I do the awkward `Meteor.setTimeout` is because `Template.rendered` is called *after every single item* that was rendered into the Template. So I need to re-confirm that it is still loading, but give it some time to either load the next one or to finish rendering them all, with a little pause until it sets `loading_stuff` to `false`.

How do I reliably query/callback at the end of all DOM updates (for a particular Template or for the whole page) the proper Meteor way?

Many thanks.

***EDIT***

The solution with using the [`subscribe()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) `onReady()` callback only partially works:

Templates are seemingly called multiple (2-3) times before the rendering even starts, but *after* the data has returned from the server that the Template relies on to render. This means that that it's 'finished' loading data, but the DOM is still being rendered. I will play around with `Meteor.autorun()` and see if I can find a reliable hook somewhere to do this properly. In the meantime, I guess my original question still remains:

How do I know when the entire Template/page has finished rendering?

***FINAL EDIT:***

At the end of the day, based on how the DOM is structured, it's up to the developer have a rock-solid DOM and attach the appropriate callbacks as best as possible to the elements he/she wants to check the state of. It may seem like an anti-climatic no-brainer, but for me the only way to know the final element of a Template is rendered is to have an element with a special id rendered at the very end of a Template that signals the end of the render and attach a `.livequery` callback to it. I hope that Meteor will incorporate a more unified and global support for checking this state in the future.

Comment: Have a look at the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532630/meteor-database-latency, while not exactly what you're looking for it may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that JQuery's livequery plugin doesn't work when waiting for elements from a template to be written to the DOM. This is because the plugin listens on JQuery methods like append, but Meteor doesn't use JQuery. It uses an object called `LiveRange` to write to the DOM. I modified my livequery JavaScript file to work with this.

Near the bottom of the file, there is a line that calls `registerPlugin()`. I modified it to look like this:

```js
$.livequery.registerPlugin([
    {object: $.fn, methods: ['append', 'prepend', 'after', 'before', 'wrap', 'attr',    'removeAttr', 'addClass', 'removeClass', 'toggleClass', 'empty', 'remove', 'html']},
    {object: LiveRange.prototype, methods: ['insertBefore', 'insertAfter']} 
]);
```

Then I modified the registerPlugin() method to look like this:

```js
registerPlugin: function(registration) {
    for (var i = 0; i < registration.length; i++) {
        var object = registration[i].object;
        var methods = registration[i].methods;

        $.each( methods, function(i,n) {
            // Short-circuit if the method doesn't exist
            if (!object[n]) return;

            // Save a reference to the original method
            var old = object[n];

            // Create a new method
            object[n] = function() {
                // Call the original method
                var r = old.apply(this, arguments);

                // Request a run of the Live Queries
                $.livequery.run();

                // Return the original methods result
                return r;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will check to see if the element exists when `insertBefore()` or `insertAfter()` is called on the `LiveRange` object and will still work with JQuery as it did before.

Comment: great stuff, I have very little time at the moment and I tried playing with livequery last night but gave up really quickly due to things simply not working with nary an insight, so it's awesome to see that I wasn't completely retarded when trying. I'm gonna try the amendments you suggest and get back to you soon, hopefully this weekend. cheers!

Comment: Glad I was able to ease your concerns over your intelligence! Hope this helps with your Meteor issues as well.

Comment: I found that for all intents and purposes livequery basically does what `Template.rendered` already does anyway; depending on how your Templates and divs inside them are structured, it just fires as many times as there are new instances rendered. At the end of the day, Meteor seems to fire re-renders quite often and sometimes unpredictably based on how the DOM is structured, so it's up to the developer have a rock-solid DOM and attach the appropriate callbacks as best as possible to the elements he/she wants to check for.

Answer (score 6):

Nesting an item template inside the current one might actually help?

```
<template name="stuff">
   {{#each items}}
     {{> itemTemplate}}
   {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="itemTemplate">
   <div class="coolView">{{cool_stuff}}</div>
</template>
```

Now the callback on Template.itemTemplate.rendered may run every time new item is updated into the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a jquery plugin like [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) to follow-up dom insertions for a specific selector:

```
$('.my-rendered-element').livequery(function () {
    console.log('I've been added to the DOM');
});
```

If you also need to make sure images have been loaded and everything is well rendered you can use some other utility like this other plugin [imagesLoaded](http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/), and do something like:

```
$('.my-rendered-element').livequery(function () {
    $(this).imagesLoaded(function() {
        console.log('My images have been loaded');
    });
});
```

It's a workaround and it maybe doesn't integrate well with Meteor, but I found these 2 guys very useful in many situations.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a partial solution is this:

Add the `onComplete()` callback to the subscriptions of my `Items` collection, which is the official end of any loading process. So, no more hacky `setTimeout`s in `Template.rendered`, just set `loading_stuff` to `true` when data is queried (in `Template.stuff.items`) and then to `false` in the `onComplete()` callback in the subscribe function:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('items', function (some_param) {
    return Items.find({some_field: some_param});
});
```

and Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('items', some_param, function onComplete() {
    Session.set('loading_stuff', false);
});
```

...

```
Template.stuff.items = function () {
    Session.set('loading_stuff', true);
    return Items.find({owner: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {created_time: -1}});
};
```

It's a partial solution because knowing when the data has arrived from the server and when the DOM has finished rendering are two separate issues.

Comment: and for those wanting to do much more interesting stuff, `Meteor.autorun` provides a way to define your own reactive context in the client, so you can do really advanced things when handling data/events/rendering. [docs here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_autorun)

Comment: Old answer but this isn't a good solution because the `Meteor.subscribe` doesn't get reran if `items` get added or removed.  So this will work for the initial loading but not reactively. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options:

1. As you mentioned in your final comment, you could create your reactive context and handle changes there.
2. You could create a special value, ie. _id = "END" and look for that value in the template rendering.
3. My favorite: instead of using a collection, populate the template as a result of a `Meteor.call` and `Meteor.methods` call pair. You could also put the result in a reactive variable so the template automatically re-renders.

As you may have already discovered, the `onReady` event of [`subscribe()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) fires when the publish method calls [`ready()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_ready), not when all the data has shipped over.

Here's a simple example of #3 above:

In the client:

```
  Meteor.call('get_complete_email',id, function(err,doc) {
    if (err === undefined) {
      // Note current_compose is reactive
      current_compose.set(new _ComposePresenter(action, doc));
    } else {
      log_error('compose','get complete email ',err);
    }
  });
```

In the server:

```
 Meteor.methods({
   'get_complete_email': function(id) {
     return Emails.findOne({_id:id, user_id:Meteor.userId}, body_message_fields);
   }
 });
```

In your presenter or viewer code:  (the `data` temp variable could be eliminated - it's legacy and hasn't been refactored out yet).

```
Template.compose_to_cc_bcc_subject.prefilled = function(part) {
  if (Current && Current.compose()) { 
    var data = Current.compose();
    if (data == undefined || data[part] == undefined) { return; }
    return data[part]; 
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to wire up current_compose, Current and your own objects a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

I do it yet another DIY way. Map an index/rank onto your cursor and then check that index against a count of the same query in your `.rendered` callback:

```
items: function() {   
   return Items.find({whatever: whatever}).map(function(item, index) {
      item.rank = index + 1;
      return item;
   });
}

Template.stuff.rendered = function() { 
  if(this.data.rank === Items.find({whatever: this.data.whatever}).count()) {
     //  Do something cool like initializing a sweet
     //  JS plugin now that ALL your template instances 
     //  are all rendered
     $("#coolplugindiv").coolJSPluginInit();
  }
}
```

I'm sure it's slightly more taxing on the server, but it works.  Thought I'm curious about `template.lastNode` and if there's some way to use that to have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to run a callback in the `onRendered` block of the next template:

```
<template name="stuff">
  {{#each items}}
    <div class="coolView">{{cool_stuff}}</div>
  {{/each}}
  {{> didMyStuffLoad}}
</template>
```

then:

```
Template.didMyStuffLoad.rendered = function () {
  Session.set('loading_stuff', false);
}
```

Everything will be loaded into the DOM before this onRendered block executes.