# Know when child templates have been rendered

Tags: meteor

```
<template name="FrameItems">
  <div class="frame-items">
    {{#each frames}}
      {{> FrameItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

In the above example, I want to know when all `FrameItem` templates inside `FrameItems` template have been rendered. I thought `onRendered` of the parent would be invoked when all the child templates have been rendered, but it was just called right away. What's the conventional way of making sure all the child templates are rendered?

Comment: There's several DIY ways to do this if you search around, but it would be nice if there was a core Meteor function for this as it's really common and helpful if you're using JS plugins that can't initialize until all DOM elements are inserted.  FYI I wrote a "add ranking and compare to a count" solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548581/callback-when-all-template-items-finished-rendering-in-meteor But it requires any JS code be ran IN the child template's `.onRendered` callback, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would proceed:

1. You create a pageSession reactive variable or reactive dictionary entry. Let's call it `lastRendered`.
2. You update it in the `onRendered` function of your `FrameItem` template using the `_id` of the related `frames` item. This way, each time a `FrameItem` template is rendered, you now which one it is.
3. You create an helper in your parent template watching your `lastRendered` reactive variable and checking if it matches your last `frames` item. It could look like that (untested code):

   ```
   lastFrameIsRendered: function() {
     var lastId = frames.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1}).fetch()._id;
     return pageSession.get ("lastRendered") === lastId;
   },
   ```

Alternatively, if you need to get a feedback in your parent template `onRendered` function, you can wrap this code into a `this.autorun(function() {` (tracker) like this:

```
var lastId = frames.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1}).fetch()._id;
this.autorun(function() {
  if (pageSession.get ("lastRendered") === lastId) {
  //do your stuff
  }
});
```

It will be executed each time there is a change in your parent template.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a counter and increment it until it reaches a certain value.
Here the counter would in `Session` and incremented until it reaches the length of your `Frames` iterable thing:

```
Template.FrameItems.onRendered(function() {
  Session.set('frameCounter', 0);
});

Template.FrameItem.onRendered(function() {
  Session.set('frameCounter', Session.get('frameCounter') + 1);
});
```

Then you simply use a tracker:

```
//Where template is your template instance, for example 'this' in an onCreated callback
template.autorun(function doStuffWhenFramesRendered(computation) {
  if(Session.get('frameCounter') === template.frames.length) {
    doStuff();
    //Stop observing
    computation.stop();
  }
});
```

Note that it takes into account the fact that `FrameItem` may render at weird times (avoiding race conditions if any), but it doesn't take into account new frames. To take those into account you would not stop the `computation`.