# Speed issue on loading page and get xhr object

Tags: meteor

I have just implemeted a super small app under 150 lines
http://songcollections.meteor.com/

It takes 5 seconds to reveal date in the table.

As I don't know much about JS DOM, what could be the problem ?

I put code there for inspection:
`http://jsfiddle.net/wodecaoxin/3ckXj/1/`

(client.js and server.js is combined for conciseness. I deploy the app with different js file in separate folders)

I split code into "client" and "server" folder. That doesn't help.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
        //publish "table" event
        Meteor.publish("table", function () {
            console.log("table signal");
            return lists.find({});
        });
        //listen
        Meteor.publish("songdetails", function (title) {
            return lists.find({
                _id: title
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Full size image Click: "open image in new tab"
[image: Full size image Click: "open image in new tab"]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The shared hosting is a bit slow. You can try putting the app on your own server to see improvements. Also, you should conside putting a "loading" message in your app: [Meteorjs loading message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171294/meteorjs-loading-message)