# How to wait for child data in meteor before showing content

Tags: meteor, spacebars

my page has a section that holds 10 games that the user owns. The games have achievements attached to them using a gameId. Currently, I am subscribing to the achievements of each game individually. This is done by using `{{#each gamesList}} {{> oneGame}} {{/each}}` and `Template.oneGame.onCreated = function() { this.subscribe('gameAchievements', this.data.gameId); }`. In this case gamesList is a helper that returns 10 subscribed game records. This works fine for getting the data and displaying it, but I am having trouble with creating a loading screen that will display until each child subscription (for achievements of each of the 10 games). How can I display a loading spinner on the parent template until all of its child subscriptions are done loading?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at this post about template-level subscriptions  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879762/displaying-loader-while-meteor-collection-loads

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Iron Router, you can check out `waitOn` in the Iron Router Guide (http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/).

Here's the code from that guide:

```
Router.route('/post/:_id', {
  // this template will be rendered until the subscriptions are ready
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',

  waitOn: function () {
    // return one handle, a function, or an array
    return Meteor.subscribe('post', this.params._id);
  },

  action: function () {
    this.render('myTemplate');
  }
});
```

Then in your 'loading' template, you can use the sacha:spin package (https://atmospherejs.com/sacha/spin) to display a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest you circumvent this kind of complexity and delay by returning the *gameAchievements* along with the *gameList* cursor? Use [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) to run the dependent query at the same time as the parent. Then you can use @jbryant04's answer to handle the spinner while waiting for the *gameList* subscription to fulfill. You'll see fewer network roundtrips and your code will be much simpler.